# Asynchronous Socket Server in C#, client to client communication through socket server

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, socketserver

I am trying to develop server/client Asynchronous sockets using c#. I have followed guide on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example) Link. In my case, socket server listening on particular endpoint, many clients can connect to server at a time, clients can talk to server and server can talk to clients. lets say client 1 and client 2 connected with server, client 1 can send message to server and server can send to client 1, same for client 2 case. Now i want clients should be able  to communicate with each other through server. For example;client 2 want to communicate with client 1, for that client 2 will send message to server (this message will contain some preset characters;), then server will receive text from client 2 and will get the handler for client 1 and send this message to client 1, client 1 will response the server, Now i want to send the response of client 1 against that message to client 2, but i do not know how to do that because client 1 communicates through its own handler with server, I am struck here, help will be highly appreciated!!
 my code is given below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;



namespace SocketServer
{
    // State object for reading client data asynchronously  
    public class StateObject
    {
        // Client  socket.  
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.  
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        // Receive buffer.  
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        // Received data string.  
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        public int clientNumber;
    }
    public class AsyncSocketServer
    {
        public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public static Dictionary<int, StateObject> Clients = new Dictionary<int, StateObject>();

        public static int connectedClient = 0;




        public AsyncSocketServer()
        {


        } 
        public static void startListening() {

            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
            int Port = 1122;

            IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            IPEndPoint EP = new IPEndPoint(IP, Port);
            Socket listner = new Socket(IP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);



            try
            {
                listner.Bind(EP);
                listner.Listen(100);

                while (true)
                {
                   allDone.Reset();

                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for the Connection......");

                    listner.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), listner);

                    allDone.WaitOne();
                }


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Occured ! in start listening method "+e.ToString());
            }

             Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");  
            Console.Read();  

        }

        public static void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            connectedClient++;
            Console.WriteLine("client number " + connectedClient);
            allDone.Set();



            Socket listner = (Socket)  ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listner.EndAccept(ar);

            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.clientNumber = connectedClient;

            Clients.Add(connectedClient, state);
           Console.WriteLine("total clients {0}",Clients.Count());

            state.workSocket = handler;
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize,0,new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack),state);

        }
        public static void ReadCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {  

        String content = String.Empty;



        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        try { 
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        state.sb.Clear();
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;  

        // Read data from the client socket.   
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);  

        if (bytesRead > 0) {  
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(  
                state.buffer,0,bytesRead));  

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read   
            // more data.  

            content = state.sb.ToString();

            if (content.Substring(0, 3) == "cmd") {
                foreach (StateObject Client in Clients.Values) {
                    if (Client.clientNumber == 1) { 
                        Console.WriteLine("value is "+Client.clientNumber);
                        if (isClientConnected(Client.workSocket)){
                            Send(Client.workSocket, "did you receive my message");
                            //now client number 1 will response through its own handler, but i want to get response of 
                            //client number 1 and return this response to client number 2

                        }
                        else {
                            string responsemsg = "client number " + Client.clientNumber + " is disconnected !";
                            Console.WriteLine(responsemsg);
                            Send(handler,responsemsg);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from client {1} socket. \n Data : {2}",
                    content.Length, state.clientNumber,content);
            // Echo the data back to the client.  

            if (isClientConnected(handler))
            {
                Send(handler, content);
            }
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), state);

        }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            //once if any client disconnected then control will come into this block
            Console.WriteLine("Socket Exception Occured in Read Call Back : " + e.Message.ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //once if any client disconnected then control will come into this block
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Occured in Read Call Back : " + e.Message.ToString());

        }
        }
        private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);



                //handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                //handler.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public static bool isClientConnected(Socket handler){

            return handler.Connected;
        }
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {

            startListening();


            return 0;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For future readers: .Net Core team recommended to don't use the "old" link in this question and use the Async suffixed methods instead. https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4828#issuecomment-643619106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any complex socket-based application, I would recommend using a socket library like [DotNetty](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty) to abstract the transport layer and allow you to focus on your application logic.  Check out their [SecureChat example](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/tree/dev/examples), it may be pretty similar to what you're trying to achieve.

I've thrown together a quick example of a DotNetty server that would allow you to send commands between clients by having the clients register with the server, and then having the server route messages between the clients.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DotNetty.Transport.Channels;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace MultiClientSocketExample
{
    public enum Command
    {
        Register = 1,  // Register a new client
        SendToClient = 2, // Send a message from one client to antoher
        DoClientAction = 3 // Replace this with your client-to-client command
    }

    // Envelope for all messages handled by the server
    public class Message
    {
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public Command Command { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

    // Command for seding a message from one client to antoher.   
    // This would be serialized as JSON and stored in the 'Data' member of the Message object.
    public class SendToClientCommand
    {
        public string DestinationClientId { get; set; }  // The client to receive the message

        public Command ClientCommand { get; set; } // The command for the destination client to execute

        public string Data { get; set; } // The payload for the destination client
    }

    // An object for storing unhandled messages in a queue to be processed asynchronously
    // This allows us to process messages and respond to the appropriate client,
    // without having to do everything in the ChannelRead0 method and block the main thread
    public class UnhandledMessage
    {
        private readonly Message message;
        private readonly IChannelHandlerContext context;

        public UnhandledMessage(Message message, IChannelHandlerContext context)
        {
            this.message = message;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public Message Message => message;
        public IChannelHandlerContext Context => context;

        public Command Command => message.Command;
        public string ClientId => message.ClientId;
        public string Data => message.Data;
    }

    // A representation of the connected Clients on the server.  
    // Note:  This is not the 'Client' class that would be used to communicate with the server.
    public class Client
    {
        private readonly string clientId;
        private readonly IChannelHandlerContext context;

        public Client(string clientId, IChannelHandlerContext context)
        {
            this.clientId = clientId;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public string ClientId => clientId;
        public IChannelHandlerContext Context => context;
    }

    // The socket server, using DotNetty's SimpleChannelInboundHandler
    // The ChannelRead0 method is called for each Message received
    public class Server : SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Message>, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Client> clients;
        private readonly ConcurrentQueue<UnhandledMessage> unhandledMessages;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellation;
        private readonly AutoResetEvent newMessage;

        public Server(CancellationToken cancellation)
        {
            this.clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Client>();
            this.newMessage = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            this.cancellation = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellation);
        }

        // The start method should be called when the server is bound to a port.
        // Messages will be received, but will not be processed unless/until the Start method is called
        public Task Start()
        {
            // Start a dedicated thread to process messages so that the ChannelRead operation does not block
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();  // This will be used to deserialize the Data member of the messages

                while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    UnhandledMessage message;
                    var messageEnqueued = newMessage.WaitOne(100);  // Sleep until a new message arrives

                    while (unhandledMessages.TryDequeue(out message))  // Process each message in the queue, then sleep until new messages arrive
                    {
                        if (message != null)
                        {
                            // Note: This part could be sent to the thread pool if you want to process messages in parallel
                            switch (message.Command)
                            {
                                case Command.Register:
                                    // Register a new client, or update an existing client with a new Context
                                    var client = new Client(message.ClientId, message.Context);
                                    clients.AddOrUpdate(message.ClientId, client, (_,__) => client);
                                    break;
                                case Command.SendToClient:
                                    Client destinationClient;
                                    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(message.Data)))
                                    {
                                        var sendToClientCommand = serializer.Deserialize<SendToClientCommand>(reader);
                                        if (clients.TryGetValue(sendToClientCommand.DestinationClientId, out destinationClient))
                                        {
                                            var clientMessage = new Message { ClientId = message.ClientId, Command = sendToClientCommand.ClientCommand, Data = sendToClientCommand.Data };
                                            destinationClient.Context.Channel.WriteAndFlushAsync(clientMessage);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, cancellation.Token);
        }

        // Receive each message from the clients and enqueue them to be procesed by the dedicated thread
        protected override void ChannelRead0(IChannelHandlerContext context, Message message)
        {
            unhandledMessages.Enqueue(new UnhandledMessage(message, context));
            newMessage.Set(); // Trigger an event so that the thread processing messages wakes up when a new message arrives
        }

        // Flush the channel once the Read operation has completed
        public override void ChannelReadComplete(IChannelHandlerContext context)
        {
            context.Flush();
            base.ChannelReadComplete(context);
        }

        // Automatically stop the message-processing thread when this object is disposed
        public void Dispose()
        {
            cancellation.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `TcpListener`? At least it supports `async/await`. rather than spinning up CPU-bound threads for something that is essentially I/O bound

Comment: DotNetty is an asynchronous, event-driven Socket IO library.   The [SecureChat example server](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/blob/dev/examples/SecureChat.Server/SecureChatServerHandler.cs) is a good start, but it just broadcasts the incoming messages to all clients, so I thought I'd demonstrate a sample of routing a message to a specific client.  I introduced the producer-consumer pattern, with a dedicated thread to process the messages, in case there's more to the server logic than just message routing.

Comment: [Here's a thread](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/issues/199) discussing DotNetty vs. TcpListener and other alternatives.  DotNetty is a port of [Netty](https://netty.io/) and is maintained by the Microsoft Azure team.  It is used for the Azure IoT gateway protocol and as the network layer for such distributed frameworks as [Akka.net](http://getakka.net/).

Comment: Thanks for links.  I took a look at the SecureChat example you mentioned and it looks to be more of a high-level EAI library (which are generally transport agnostic) than a TCP socket lib.  There's nothing wrong with that but it's not a apples vs apples comparison.  Anyway, your example may work but it resembles old school overlapped I/O techniques of spawning a thread and sleeping on a handle.  It's not the recommended approach of using `Task`s and additionally wasteful of a thread that would otherwise be better doing other things whilst IOCP is going on in the background. Wishing you well +1

Comment: I downloaded DotNetty from https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty and but after opening solution, its giving errors for namespace issue, i think this DotNetty solution will open in visual studio 2017, Well, i am downloading visual studio 2017 community edition and running the project, and will to try get result as per my need.

Comment: I tried DotNetty, and tring to focus on code,  I noticed that this socket server broadcasting messages to all connected clients, , its need much experience to alter the library to only send message to particular client, can you please advice me , where should i go now after this, to alter the default behavior of library.

Comment: Can you upload your code (or an equivalent sample reproducing the behavior) so we can take a look?

Comment: #Aaron M.Eshbach  , I have edited the question section, with code and my comments, please read. help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do the same, also based on the same code of MSDN
a possible solution is to use a list of sockets:

```
List<Socket> clients = new List<Socket>();
```

then, when a client connects, add the client to the list:

```
public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.  
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        clients.Add(handler);
        ...
    }
```

You have to know the id ( handle )of each client connected, and then you can send some message to a specific client:

```
 public void SendToOne(string id,string message)
    {
        foreach (Socket s in clients)
        {
            if (s.Handle.ToString() == id)
            {
                Send(s, message);
            }
        }

    }
```